# Getting j.i.IOException: Premature close in Gatling

Tags: performance-testing, gatling, scala-gatling

I have a few GET endpoints related to downloading files from the server. And when we try to simulate the download for smaller size it works perfectly fine ex : 500MB but for 1GB above files it starts the download in gatling and after some time it stopped with error **j.i.IOException: Premature** also I have verified that it is not something related to the application as it works perfectly fine in Loadrunner.

Observation: file download would take more than 1 minute.
I was looking into the Gatling Config file and updated following but non of them helped to resolve the issue
shutdownTimeout,connectTimeout,handshakeTimeout,pooledConnectionIdleTimeout

Answer (score 2):

The timeout you have to increase is the [`requestTimeout`](https://github.com/gatling/gatling/blob/main/gatling-core/src/main/resources/gatling-defaults.conf#L95).

Comment: I have already updated it to :  requestTimeout = 60000000 and still not working

Comment: it got resolved once I removed the logback-test.xml file

Comment: @Lusitha Wondering how you knew to remove the logback-test.xml file and why that fixed it.  Was it luck or do you know the reasoning?